# Creating bitcoin raw transaction takes all balance

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoin-testnet

I am creating a raw transaction using the bitcoin testnet, but when I push the raw transaction onto the network it takes all my balance. Am I suppose to send the remaining 'change' back to myself? Here is the code im using to create the raw transaction:

```
var bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');

var keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('cMvPQZiG5mLARSjxbBwMxKwzhTHaxgpTsXB6ymx7SGAeYUqF8HAT', bitcoin.networks.testnet);
var tx = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(bitcoin.networks.testnet);

tx.addInput('87502f792d477f0514a92486c875fa1fb631fd68c95ccf458c264155165a95c6', 1);
tx.addOutput('msWccFYm5PPCn6TNPbNEnprA4hydPGadBN', 10000);
tx.sign(0, keyPair);

console.log(tx.build().toHex());
```

Am I correct in thinking i also have to send myself back my remaining amount? so for example if my original balance was 0.00114 BTC I would do this:

```
tx.addInput('87502f792d477f0514a92486c875fa1fb631fd68c95ccf458c264155165a95c6', 1);

// senders address
tx.addOutput('ms9ySK54aEC2ykDviet9jo4GZE6GxEZMzf ', 104000);

// receivers address
tx.addOutput('msWccFYm5PPCn6TNPbNEnprA4hydPGadBN', 10000);
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in thinking i also have to send myself back my remaining amount?

Yes, you are correct. Any funds that are not sent to any specific address can be claimed by the miner as a transaction fee. This is how the transaction fee is created.

Check out the first bitcoin transaction made by Satoshi Nakamoto to Hal Finney in [Block 170](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/block/00000000d1145790a8694403d4063f323d499e655c83426834d4ce2f8dd4a2ee). Satoshi sent 10BTC to Hal and 40 back to himself. Since it was so early, there was no need for a transaction fee because they were mining the blocks themselves. Today, if you tried to send a transaction with no fee, the nodes would reject it (min. relay fee not met), but even a low fee miners would probably choose not to mine it any time soon (if ever).

[image: block 170]

Comment: This is kind of a bad example as he sent the change back to the same address; it's best practice to generate a new address for receiving the change. This is also what a Bitcoin wallet will do today.

Comment: Yes good point, for privacy you should always use a new address for change. This is typically done using hierarchical deterministic key generation see BIP32